# error swift 3 Downcast from 'PHAsset?' to 'PHAsset' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

I have this strange error and don't have any idea hot to fix it.

My code was working well in Xcode 7.3. But, after updating to Xcode 8 I got nearly 17 errors and 21 warnings.This might be some syntax change in Swift 3

Solved all those but can't figure out this one : Downcast from 'PHAsset?' to 'PHAsset' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

help please

```
let valorFoto = tuplesFoto.valorfoto.substring(to: tuplesFoto.valorfoto.characters.index(tuplesFoto.valorfoto.endIndex, offsetBy: -4))

            if let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [valorFoto], options: nil).firstObject as? PHAsset
            {
                PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (data: Data?, identificador: String?, orientaciomImage: UIImageOrientation, info: [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Void in

                    if let data = data
                    {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: data)
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                                self.images.updateValue(image, forKey: tuplesFoto.valorfoto)
                                self.colDragAndDrop.reloadData()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })

            }
            else
            {
                if let image = UIImage(named: "no_media")
                {
                    images.updateValue(image, forKey: tuplesFoto.valorfoto)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like `fetchAssets` returns a `PHAsset?`. Have you tried just removing the `as? PHAsset`?

Comment: it worked. I served your answer thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The line of code:
before

```
if let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [valorFoto], options: nil).firstObject as? PHAsset
```

after

```
if let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [valorFoto], options: nil).firstObject
```